# Linq to xml not able to add new elements

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml

We save our xml in a "text" field in the database. So first I check if it exist any xml, if not I create a new xdocument, fill it with the necessary xml. else i just add the new element. Code looks like this:

```
XDocument doc = null;
if (item.xmlString == null || item.xmlString == "")
                {
                    doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"), new XElement("DataTalk", new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
                        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"), new XElement("Posts", new XElement("TalkPost"))));

                }
                else
                {
                    doc = XDocument.Parse(item.xmlString);
                }
```

This is working alright to create a structure, but then the problem appears, when I want to add new TalkPost. I get an error saying incorrectly structured document. 
The following code when adding new elements:

```
doc.Add(new XElement("TalkPost", new XElement("PostType", newDialog.PostType), 
new XElement("User", newDialog.User), new XElement("Customer", newDialog.Customer),
new XElement("PostedDate", newDialog.PostDate), new XElement("Message", newDialog.Message)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `doc.Add(...`, try `doc.Root.Add(...`

Adding another element to doc means that you are essentially trying to add another root element, hence the invalid XML exception.

In response to the comment:

I think you should try then `doc.Root.Element("Posts").Add(...` As that will add an element to the `Posts` element, rather than the root.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, now it's working, the only problem I get now is that it gets saven in the same "level" as "Posts", but it should be saved below Posts like:  <DataTalk> <Posts> and then all the <TalkPost>  </TalkPost> </Posts> </DataTalk>   Thanks alot